# make the program stop if missing value is above threshold

Tags: python, oop

I'm organising python codes from jupyter notebook to OOP styles in text editors.
I'd like to make the program to ingest data, check for the max null values, and if it's above the threshold, print customised messages and stop the program.

for example:

```
class ProcessData():
    def read_data(path):
        df = pd.read_csv(path)
        # Deal with NA values
        try:
            max_null = df.isnull().mean().max()
        except max_null > 0.01:
            raise Exception(f"Missing value percentage too high: {max_null}. Review data")
        else:
            df.dropna(inplace=True， inplace=True)
        return df
```

Is this correct ? or overly complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to use `if` for this, except is expecting an Exception that inherits from BaseException

https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

```
if condition:
    raise Exception(f"failed due to {condition}")
```

You can also avoid creating a class that does only does one thing; simply creating a file with a `.py` extension and putting your function(s) into it is sufficient to create a new namespace

```py
import myfile  # namespace from myfile.py

myfile.function_in_myfile()
```